# how to join multi select in SQL/PHP

Tags: php, sql

Haven't found a good answer for this one yet. What do I need to add to run both select statements below. I tried Union ALL and a few other things but it doesn't return data. Any help would be appreciated. 
Trying to do this with a table. 
[New table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqFZJ.png)

```
    $sql = "select
         bin_loc as [Yard Location],
         status as [Status],
         item_no as [Equipment #]
         from location WHERE type like 'YARD'";

   $sql = "select
         item_no as [Equipment],
         status as [Status],
         bin_loc as [Yard Location]
         from location WHERE type like 'DOCK'";


 $stmt = $db->query($sql);
 $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
 foreach ($result as $row) {
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp    look at OR.

Comment: No, you will not be able to run 2 queries with one statement unless you're using `mysqli_multi_query`. However, using a `UNION ALL` should work, or run them as separate queries. Though since you're getting the same information from the same table, use `OR`, and if you want them grouped, use `ORDER BY`

Comment: `select bin_loc as [Yard Location], status as [Status], item_no as [Equipment #] from location WHERE  type in('YARD', 'DOCK')` I think should do it.

Comment: I only see one `SELECT` statement.  Where is the other?

Comment: I suggest you trim your example to only include the SQL since PHP isn't relevant to this question.

Comment: Why is this getting so many down votes? To help the OP learn and improve identifying why they are down voted would be good.  E.g. suggesting setting up a [rextest](http://rextester.com/FIQQ26849). Or indicate they have not demonstrated sufficient research first.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. My biggest opportunity is showing the fields in the order that I have them. I think aynber nailed what I need to do. Giving that a run for it.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement you posted is not valid SQL, which is why it is not returning any data. A UNION ALL should work, if the resulting query is valid. Column names must match for a UNION to work.

This should return the data you are looking for:

```
SELECT 
  bin_loc as [Yard Location],
  status as [Status],
  item_no as [Equipment]
FROM location 
WHERE type like 'YARD'

UNION ALL

SELECT
  bin_loc as [Yard Location],
  status as [Status],
  item_no as [Equipment]
FROM location 
WHERE type like 'DOCK'
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating 2 tables to do what I needed instead of trying to do it in all in one table due to the fields needing to be in a certain order for presentation. Includes the php and SQL for those that are new to this like me. 
Thank you for all the assistance.

```
 1st table:
                     <tbody>
                                <?php 
                                    $database = new Connection();
                                    $db = $database->openConnection();
                                    $sql = "select
                                                bin_loc as [Yard Location],
                                                status as [Status],
                                                item_no as [Equipment#]
                                                from location
                                                WHERE type like 'YARD'";
                                    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
                                    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
                                    foreach ($result as $row) {
                                ?>
                                        <tr class="gradeX">
                                            <td><?= $row["Yard Location"</td>
                                            <td><?= $row["Status"] ?></td>
                                            <td><?= $row["Equipment#"] ?</td>
                                         </tr>                    
                               <?php
                                    } 
                               ?>
                                </tbody>

Second table
                   <tbody>
                                <?php
                                    $sql = "select
                                                item_no as [Equipment],
                                                status as [Status],
                                                bin_loc as [Dock Location]
                                                from location
                                                WHERE type like 'DOCK'";
                                    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
                                    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
                                    foreach ($result as $row) {
                                ?>
                                        <tr class="gradeX">
                                            <td><?= $row["Equipment"] ?></td>
                                            <td><?= $row["Status"] ?></td>
                                            <td><?= $row["Dock Location"</td>
                                         </tr>                       
                               <?php
                                    } 
                                    $database->closeConnection();
                               ?>
                                </tbody>
```